# How to export without Normals

Tags: normals, three.js

I was advised to export a model - which I'm using in a THREE js website - *without* Normals.

How exactly do you do that? I'm not seeing that as an option when I try to export it (it's a ".gltf" file - but I also have it as a ".obj" file.)

I have a model that has 4,832 Vertices in it and I was hoping to display maybe 3,000 instances of it on screen at the same time. It's working - but its severely slowing down my machine - sometimes the browser crashes. So I'm trying to figure out solutions to this - and that's where the suggestion to export without Normals came in. I'm quite new to 3D Modeling - just downloaded a free version of Blender a week go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, at some point, Blender versions started hiding the relevant section, displaying it in the export window as collapsed by default, leading to its options not being immediately visible at first glance. The section in question is called **Geometry**. Expand it, and you will see the **Write Normals** checkbox.

[image]

Comment: I see. It is indeed well hidden. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to do this with Collada dae files?